# Sensors for detecting heavy metals in indoor dust

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor

Does anyone know about a kind of sensors (or how to construct) that could be used together with ex an Arduino or other microprocessor to measure the amount of heavy metals (like lead for example) in indoor dust particles.

The goal of the project is to create a device capable of detecting and logging data about harmful heavy metals in indoor environments.

Answer (score 2):

Small physics departments have been getting rid of their neutron howitzers. They have a bit of plutonium and beryllium in a stainless steel slug in a big tub of paraffin. There are ports filled with stacks of acrylic and that is where you put your filter. Thermal neutrons radio-activate whatever you have and you quickly, because some of the half-lives are very short, stick it in a gamma ray spectrometer with multi-channel scaler (they are throwing those out as well - scored one a while back). Maybe you can snag a setup. Baseless radiation paranoia makes the howitzer hard to get, and keep. However, there are direction on making your own proton accelerator in "The Scientific American Book of Projects for the Amateur Scientist" from 1960 ( the things we used to do in our basements!).

On a more practical level, I would bet the least expensive route is a chemical dip and color test, with filters for specific reaction colors or a simple spectrophotometer. There are filter papers made with the same refractive index as some solvents, so that it vanishes when immersed.

Answer (score 1):

[Laser-induced breakdown spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_breakdown_spectroscopy) sounds more portable than the old atomic absorption or X-ray fluorescence methods, but you're still going to have to collect dust samples on filters, and subject those to the care of an expensive, and likely quite large, machine. See for example [TSI](http://www.tsi.com/ChemReveal-LIBS-Desktop-Analyzer/) or [Applied Spectra](http://www.appliedspectra.com/products/index.html).
NASA's [Curiosity Rover's chem-cam laser system](http://www.osa-opn.org/home/articles/volume_24/january_2013/features/zapping_mars_using_lasers_to_determine_the_chemist/#.UtNEdvaj2WY) will probably pick up lead, and is likely small enough to be easily portable, but you'll still need to build a sample filter unit for the thing unless you're willing to burn holes in the floor underneath dust-bunnies. Still, the cost of such a unit will make an Arduino nothing more than a cheap dongle hanging off to the side.

Answer (score 1):

If it is mainly Lead (or Mercury) you are looking for:

Lead can be detected quantitatively in very low concentrations as PbS by photometry, i.e. by measuring the absorption of light of a certain wavelength in a solution.

It could be realized e.g. by bubbeling a known volume of air through a H<sub>2</sub>S solution (attention: poisonous and very bad smelling) and then measuring how much light of an appropriate light source (LED) is absorbed by the solution.

See this for [(somewhat simplistic) example](http://www.rsc.org/Education/EiC/issues/2007Sept/BuildYourOwnSpectrophotometer.asp).

This method is sensitive enough e.g. to measure quantitatively the amount of lead in human hair picked up from the environment (air).

Answer (score 1):

A common way to measure concentrations of heavy metals is with xray spectroscopy.  This is not something appropriate for a typical hobbyist, but I'm mentioning it here for completeness and because there are portable commercial units that do exactly what you are asking for based on this principle.

Basically, if you crash enough high-energy photons into them, atoms will re-emit this energy as light of specific wavelengths.  The emissions of different elements are unique, like a fingerprint.

There are off the shelf hand-held instruments that do exactly this.  One I am familiar with is made by Thermo Fisher, but I think there are others making them too.  The one from Thermo Fisher that I've seen is gun-shaped.  You point the gun at the sample you want to analyze and pull the trigger.  It shoots out xrays at various known wavelengths and strengths, and analyzes the return emissions.  Software then figures out the concentration of various elements in the sample.  It also contains a library of common alloys and can tell you directly what kind of stainless steel you have, for example.

These things do cost 1000s of dollars, so this isn't something you want to get for the fun of it.  Making miniature xray tubes is also not something the average hobbyist can or should attempt.  Designing these things is 60% science and 50% dark magic.